# Rails 5: Restrict HTTParty query to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on the implementation of Typeform's API. I'm able to fetch the responses, but I need to display the responses assigend to the user.

When a typeform is submitted a `hidden_field` is passed to Typeform which is `current_user.hash_id`.

All good so far. I can also set a restriction for the API with a `parameter` called `query`.

So my request currently looks like:

```
  def get_data
    self.class.get("/forms/XXXXX/responses?page_size=25&query=", headers: { "Authorization" => @auth})
  end
```

I would need to add `current_user.hash_id` to the `&query=`, but since I'm making this request out of my model, I'm not able to use `current_user`.

Therefore, should I pass the logic to my `controller` to make `current_user` accesible or is there another way to call `current_user` safely in my `model` ?

Comment: where do you call `get_data`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Rails 5.2

So I did the following:

I created a `module` in `lib` to acces `:user`

```
module Current
 thread_mattr_accessor :user
end
```

Afterwards I added this to my `ApplicationController`

```
around_action :set_current_user

def set_current_user
  Current.user = current_user
  yield
 ensure
  Current.user = nil
 end
```

You'll also need to add `config.autoload_paths` to your `àpplication.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Afterwards you'll need to restart the server.

Finally, you can acces `Current.user` in your model, for example:

```
  def get_data
    self.class.get("/forms/XXXXX/responses?page_size=25&query=#{Current.user.hash_id}", headers: { "Authorization" => @auth})
  end
```

Comment: Where are you calling that `get_data` method? Using a concept like a current something inside models is a code smell, there must be a better way to do what you need to do (for example, add a parameter `def get_data(current_user)`.